# A Mordell equation $y^3=x^2+20$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Recently I met a problem when I'm studying algebraic number theory.

**Problem.**  *Find all positive integer solutions of $y^3=x^2+20$*.

I solved the situation when $x$ is an odd because the two ideals $(x+2\sqrt{-5})\text{ and }(x-2\sqrt{-5})$ are relatively prime, so it must be a cube of a principal ideal for the ideal class number of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is $2$. But when $x$ is an even, let $x=2k$, then I know that $(k+\sqrt{-5})=IJ^3$, where $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, and $J$ is also a ideal. I don't know how to deal with it for they aren't principal ideals anymore. I believe that there is a unique solution $(x,y)=(14,6)$, and wish that someone could solve it.

I'm also interested in whether there is a method by elementary number theory, thanks.

Comment: See Links section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve for databases of known solutions.

Comment: Hint: even if $x$ is even, the ideals $(x\pm 2\sqrt{-5})$ are conjugate, hence have the same valuation at the unique prime above $2$… but this should definitely be on MSE rather than MO.

Comment: @Aphelli I knew that they have the valuation at $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$, and both $IJ$ and $J^2$ are principal ideals, but I still don't know what to do next.

Comment: This implies that the ideal $(x \pm 2\sqrt{-5})$ has a cube root, and the class group computation shows that this cube root must be principal. In other words, $x \pm 2\sqrt{-5}$ is a cube.

Comment: @Aphelli I got it. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Note this is cross-posted on Math SE at [A Mordell Equation $y^3=x^2+20$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4822062/602049). Note that cross-posting is generally frowned on, especially if it's done within less than about a week's time. Also, if you do cross-post, please provide a link within each post to the other one, to help avoid people duplicating efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation corresponds to the (Mordell) elliptic curve with [LMFDB label 10800.i1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/10800/i/1). The LMFDB confirms that $(14, 6)$ is the unique integral point with positive entries.

(The way that the LMFDB computed this is via Cremona's [mwrank](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgaj/mwrank/) library, which uses descent on the elliptic curve and is very general.